# Reading multiple files from a same folder using python

Tags: python, operating-system

I have thousands of text files which I want to read using python. I have successfully read one file and now I am not sure how to read multiple files using loop or any other command

I tried to split the name and type of the file by saving the variable character of the text files saved in a string.
e.g
I have 3 files named as file_1, file_2, file_3

I took one variable and limit ="1" and conciniate it with the full address of the file. now I want to know how can I access the other two files. provided I don't want to use same line of code multiple times because in reality I have
thousands of files

```
import os
from os import path
limit1 = "1"
strpath = r"C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/SP/text_file_r_w"
print("Your current directory is : %s"  %path.abspath(strpath))
f = open("C:/Users/saqibshakeel035/Desktop/SP/text_file_r_w/file_" + 
limit1 + ".txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

This code is working fine for 1 file. Now i want my code to read multile files and later on I will transfer my files to somewhere else.

Comment: What exactly prevents you from using a loop?

Answer (score 7):

You can use glob.glob to access all file paths of the folder, and read each file using for loop.

```
files = [file for file in glob.glob("../somefolder/*")]
for file_name in files:
    with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `os.walk` to scan all files in a directory.

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('lang/'):
    for file in files:
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        if extension == '.txt':
            # Do Some Task
```

Note that if you can filter by filename or file extension.

For example, if you want to get files that contains 'hello' in filename, you can also add

```
if 'hello' in filename:
    # Do Some Task
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a loop for this:

```
import os
def main():
    for dirName, subDirList, fileList in os.walk('path'):
        for subDir in subDirList:
            for file in fileList:
                #Do something with file
main()
```

This recursively goes through your files in a given directory. Note that this also goes through files in any other subdirectory in the parent directory. To instead ignore subdirectories do this:

```
import os
def main():
    for dirName, subDirList, fileList in os.walk('path'):
        for file in fileList:
            #Do something with file
main()
```

Of course you also have other [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory).